# CORS problem origins between React 18 and Symfony 6

Tags: reactjs, symfony, cors, api-platform.com, nelmiocorsbundle

I have some problem with CORS between a React web app and a Symfony API with API Platform...

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': null
```

```
###> nelmio/cors-bundle ###
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN='^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:3000)/?$'
###< nelmio/cors-bundle ###
```

and this is how I make my request with react :

```
axios.post(URL + "/login_check", credentials)
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

`export const URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api"`
I already try to make the wors allow to * and I followed many issues resolution without success...

I just want to access to my back end without CORS allow problem

Edit : I tried with postman and it works ! but not with my react Application...

Comment: CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN='^https?://(localhost|127.0.0.1|127.0.0.1:8000)(:3000)?$'

Comment: Postman works because it does not enforce CORS check. CORS is a safety system used by browser; it is the browser that blocks your response after receiving the origin header, if it finds that the allowed origins do not match with the curren URL. You can still use Postman to see how the CORS header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set in the response.

Comment: Thanks, this and : allow_credentials: true this added to nelmio_cors.yaml and it works !